# Во весь экран js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как развернуть бразуер во всеь экран при заходе на страницу веб сайта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует [window.resizeTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo), но оно практически нигде не поддерживается.

Ответ - никак.

Answer (score 2):

На всякий случай - полноэкранный режим: [fullscreen API](http://html5.by/blog/fullscreen-javascript-api/).